# Xcode 4 Interface Builder Performing Undesired Auto-resize of Controls

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I'm new to Xcode, and I'm having issues with Xcode auto-resizing controls when I add them to a view. Literally every control I try to add to the view is resized to fill the entire view, and I cannot figure out how to manually resize the controls and/or disable resize to fill in the first place. How does one go about this?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Ah. In a fit of noobishness, I failed to realize that I was adding controls to the view controller. Whooooops.